# Spring cloud config load client bootstrap.properties from AWS S3

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

At the moment I have setup a cloud config server, and client applications get properties from this one central properties. When changes are pushed to GIT, the cloud config server through rabbitmq pushes these config changes to clients and it works perfectly.

However, I would like that all client applications load the boostrap.properties that have properties such as the following from the cloud;

```
spring.application.name=app-name
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://user:pass@sub.domain.com:8888
spring.cloud.config.username=username
spring.cloud.config.password=password
```

My problem originates from the fact that I have several tenants using the same platform, and I'd like that each tenant has a different configuration file which is stored on S3 or any other common repository. This file can be pushed to different tenant setups through CI/CD, and would contain links to tenant configuration APIs etc.

Is there a way to load bootstrap properties from distributed file systems such as HDFS, or AWS S3?

Comment: You can always mount s3 folders onto a filesystem. There is much information about this in the internet and in so.

Comment: I'd actually ideally like to override the part where the boostrap.properties file is loaded, and use the aws sdk to load this from a specific path in s3. Not sure if I can wire this easily though - this is what I am searching for at the moment.

Comment: That's going to be a fairly deep thing.  Why not ask instead about creating some custom code to override where you get the properties from in spring boot.

Comment: Also look into this:  http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration  It uses git, but I bet it can be extended!

Comment: Yes my setup already uses git, but my intention is to have one tenant loading properties from 1 config server, and another tenant from another server. I think I am on my way to just override properties when submitting the jar using -Dspring.cloud.config.uri=value...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on using spring cloud-config with s3 as the backend for storing the config.

https://nageshrsalunke.me/blogs/2019/spring-cloud-config-s3-backend/

### Why S3 ?

Following are specific reasons to not use git and Use S3 for config storage

- Not exposing git/source control to production deployments environment.
- Avoiding copying/cloning or maintaing a git server in prod environments.
- Using storage for storage and version control for version control (Single Responsibility principle)
- Deployment pipeline defines when to push config / Not your source or code review system

### Implementation

Use S3EnvironmentRepository which implements EnvironmentRepository of spring "org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepository"

I have a sample implementation which fetches s3 config at schedule on change of version header in the version file from s3
https://github.com/nagesh-salunke/spring-cloud-config-s3

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)